# Asymptotes of a primitive

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a primitivable function such that any primitive has asymptotes at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. Prove that any oblique line intersects $G_f$ in at least one point.

I am quite unsure of how I am supposed to approach this. I am not sure, but I assume that "has asymptotes at $-\infty$ and $+\infty$" means horizontal and oblique asymptotes (at least one of them). If $F$ is a primitive who has an oblique asymtote $mx+n$ at $+\infty$, then, from $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{F(x)}{x} = m$, using l'Hospital's rule, we obtain $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = m$, but I don't know how to continue.

Can you give me some help?

Comment: Use [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). For function $f$, you know you can reach any value between $m_{-\infty}$ and $m_\infty$. Any oblique line goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ of the other way around. Subtract the two

Comment: Can you expand a bit more? Why is it any value $m$? Also, I assumed that an oblique asymptote exists, however, maybe there are only horizontal ones.

Comment: If the primitive has asymptote at $\pm\infty$ it means that the function $f$ has horizontal asymptotes at $\pm\infty$. If the asymptote of the primitive is horizontal it just means that the asymptote of $f$ is $0$.